# Convert SQL to Linq expression

Tags: c#, linq, linqpad

I'm looking a way to convert this query:

```
 Select *
     From  Tasks
     Where Addresses_Street1+' '+Addresses_Street2+' '+Addresses_City +' '+Addresses_ZipCode Like '%'+replace(ltrim(rtrim('Leon Deladriere 15')),' ','%')
```

to a Linq C# expression.

I know that Contains() and Trim() can be use for the method but how to handle the replace ' ' by '%' ?

This expression is used to provide to user one single input with an address and look into multiples columns to find a matching one.

I use Linqpad but I doesn't see equivalent in Linq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try.

```
(from r in Tasks where SqlMethods.Like(
    r.Addresses_Street1 + " " + 
    r.Addresses_Street2 + " " + 
    r.Addresses_City + " " + 
    r.Addresses_ZipCode, 
    "%Leon Deladriere 15".Trim().Replace(" " , "%")) 
    select r)
```

Note, LinqSql is smart enough to know that it can do the Trim and Replace locally rather than asking Sql to do it.

However if you use a field rather than a constant, eg

```
(from r in Task  where SqlMethods.Like( ... , 
    r.Addresses_Street1 + " " + 
    r.Addresses_Street2 + " " + 
    r.Addresses_City + " " + 
    r.Addresses_ZipCode,      
    r.AnotherField.Trim().Replace(" " , "%")) 
    select r)
```

then this will ask sql to do the trim and replace.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var user = "Leon Deladriere 15".Trim();
Tasks.Where(t => (t.Addresses_Street1 + t.Addresses_Street2 + t.Addresses_City + t.Addresses_ZipCode).Contains(user));
```